# listing entry position of matric satisfying certain condition

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a column vector of polynomials in Mathematica and I have divided each of the entries of the vector by another polynomial. Some of the entries are now polynomials, and other are fractions of polynomials. Is it possible to list the position of all the entries that are polynomials?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the intrinsic function `PolynomialQ` might help but without seeing your code it's difficult to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

```
genRndPoly[grade_,var_,max_] := Product[var - RandomInteger[{1,max}], {i, grade}]
rndDivisor = genRndPoly[1, w, 1];
f[max_] := Total@(Boole/@PolynomialQ/@(#/rndDivisor &/@ 
                                            Table[genRndPoly[5, w, max], {100}]))
DiscretePlot[f[max], {max, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]